# OpenCV camera rotation in iOS

Tags: opencv, io, rotation, swift5

I used openCV camera in my application. The OpenCV camera is working fine either in landscape left or landscape right. I set the orientation as below

```
-(void)initOpenCVCamera:(UIImageView*)imgView{

    VideoCamera *vcamera = [[VideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imgView];
    vcamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    vcamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    vcamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
    vcamera.delegate = self;
    vcamera.recordVideo = NO;
    vcamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
    vcamera.rotateVideo = YES;
    vcamera.defaultFPS = 30;    
}
```

The default orientation set it to Landscape Right in the above code. But i wanted to support both landscape left and landscape right orientation. So i implemented the delegate methods of OpenCV camera as below

```
@interface VideoCamera : CvVideoCamera

- (void)updateOrientation;
- (void)layoutPreviewLayer;

@end

@implementation VideoCamera
- (void)updateOrientation
{
    self->customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.parentView.frame.size.width, self.parentView.frame.size.height);
    [self layoutPreviewLayer];
}

- (void)layoutPreviewLayer
{
    if (self.parentView != nil)
    {
        CALayer* layer = self->customPreviewLayer;
        CGRect bounds = self->customPreviewLayer.bounds;
        int rotation_angle = 0;
        switch (self.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight:
                rotation_angle = 0;
                break;
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                rotation_angle = 180;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        layer.position = CGPointMake(self.parentView.frame.size.width/2., self.parentView.frame.size.height/2.);
        layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_RADIANS(rotation_angle) );
        layer.bounds = bounds;
    }
}
@end
```

But it is not working. I don't know what is the "rotation_angle" i suppose to set.